# Go lang is it possible to create a struct that can also be used as a slice?

Tags: go

Is it possible to have a struct in go that can also be accessed as a slice?
So, for example, I'd want something like this:

```
type Item struct {
    Name string
}

type ItemList struct {
    PackDate time.Time
    []Item
}
```

And then I could access an Item in the ItemList as a slice.

```
myItemList[0].Name
```

Or access the members of ItemList in the normal struct way.

```
myItemList.PackDate
```

If this is not possible, are there any recommended patterns for handling a sort of slice with metadata like this in go?

Comment: No. What's wrong with having the slice as normal field in the struct?

Comment: It just seemed like a common use case to have a list which also has some metadata attached, so I was wondering if there was a shorthand way of writing myItemList.Item[0].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended thing to do is to simply access the slice as a struct field:

```
type Item struct {
    Name string
}

type ItemList struct {
    PackDate time.Time
    Items    []Item
}
```

Accessing the values:

```
myItemList.Items[0].Name
myItemList.PackDate
```

Iterating over the slice:

```
for _, item := range myItemList.Items {
    // do something with item.Name
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the answer to the first question (can you combine struct and slice) is "no".  And the answer to the second question (recommended way to handle this use case) is just to use a normal struct containing a slice and don't try to take a shortcut :)